# Custom colour in TailwindCSS not appearing in navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have created a navbar with the pages Home, About, and Contact. I need to change the colour of the text of the active page in the navbar to green. For example, if I'm viewing the "Home" page, then the text of the "Home" page should be green in the navbar. The same for the other pages. Here is the code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Navbar = () => {
  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPath(window.location.pathname);
  }, []);
  const isCurrentPath = (url) => {
    return currentPath === url;
  };

  return (
    <nav className="bg-transparent top-0 pt-12 pr-24">
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <img src="logo.png" className="h-8 w-auto pl-24" alt="Logo" />
        </div>
        <div className="ml-auto">
          <a href="/" className={`text-white ml-4 ${isCurrentPath('/') ? 'text-custom_green' : ''}`}>Home</a>
          <a href="/about" className={`text-white ml-4 ${isCurrentPath('/about') ? 'text-custom_green' : ''}`}>About</a>
          <a href="/contact" className={`text-white ml-4 ${isCurrentPath('/contact') ? 'text-custom_green' : ''}`}>Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

The green which I want to use is a custom colour which I've defined in my tailwind.config.js file as shown below.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
      colors: {
        custom_green: "#0F682E",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

The problem is that the custom green doesn't show on the navbar. The text remains white.

I tried using default colours instead and they work perfectly so I'm guessing there isn't anything wrong with the code.

I also tried using my custom green colour on other elements and it works. For example,

`<div className="text-custom_green">Hello</div>`

Here, the custom green colour works and my text turns green. It only seems to not work for the navbar.

The only time the custom green shows up in the navbar is when I modify my tailwind.config.js file from

theme-->extend-->colors to theme-->colors. However, when I do this the default colors won't work and I don't want that. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi man kindly replace your code with this I am run your code and fix the issue.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Navbar = () => {
  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPath(window.location.pathname);
  }, []);
  const isCurrentPath = (url:any) => {
    return currentPath === url;
  };

  return (
    <nav className="bg-transparent top-0 pt-12 pr-24">
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <img src="logo.png" className="h-8 w-auto pl-24" alt="Logo" />
        </div>
        <div className="ml-auto">
          <a href="/" className={`ml-4 ${isCurrentPath('/') ? 'text-custom_green' : 'text-white'}`}>Home</a>
          <a href="/about" className={`ml-4 ${isCurrentPath('/about') ? 'text-custom_green' : 'text-white'}`}>About</a>
          <a href="/contact" className={`ml-4 ${isCurrentPath('/contact') ? 'text-custom_green' : 'text-white'}`}>Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

**NOTE**
you are using text-white this class by default that's why other text class not applied.